# ¿Cómo quedarme con los registros duplicados de dos columnas en SQL?

Tags: postgresql, sql

Necesito obtener una lista de los nombres de los empleados que asistieron a más de una sesión de capacitación el mismo día y debo incluir los nombres de las sesiones de capacitación y sus fechas de asistencia. Para ello tengo dos tablas:

**training_details**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**employee**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
WITH t1 as (
    SELECT a.employee_name, b.*
 FROM employees a
    LEFT JOIN training_details b
    ON a.employee_id = b.employee_id)
,
t2 as ( 
SELECT count (employee_id) as employee_n,
employee_name, training_session, training_date, 
FROM t1 
GROUP BY employee_name, training_session, training_date)

SELECT employee_name, training_session, training_date 
FROM t2 
WHERE employee_n > 1 ;
```

Comment: Revisa la clausula HAVING que va después del GROUP BY.

Comment: Bienvenido Absence a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Por favor indica que problema has tenido.

Comment: Perdón, lo que tienes que usar es la opción OVER para convertir la función de agregado en función de ventana.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionó.con la cláusula HAVING.